# Query to see if a field contains a string using Query DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to filter Kibana for a field that contains the string "pH".  The field is called `extra.monitor_value_name`.  Examples of potential values are `Temperature_ABC01`, `DO_ABC01`, or `pH_ABC01`.

Kibana's Elasticsearch Query DSL does not seem to have a "contains string" so I need to custom make a query.

I am new to Query DSL, can you help me create the query?

Also, is it proper to call it Query DSL?  I'm not even sure of proper wording.

Comment: Please add mapping of index and sample document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay!  Circling back with an answer to my own question.

My initial problem stemmed from not knowing about `field_name` vs `field_name.keyword`.  Read here for info on keyword here: [What's the difference between the 'field' and 'field.keyword' fields in Kibana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370280/whats-the-difference-between-the-field-and-field-keyword-fields-in-kibana)

**Solution 1**

Here's the query I ended up using.  I used a regexp query.  I found [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/23-useful-elasticsearch-example-queries) useful in figuring out syntax for the regexp:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "extra.monitor_value_name.keyword": "pH.*"
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution 2**

Another way I could have filtered, without Query DSL was typing in a search field: `extra.monitor_value_name.keyword:pH*`.
One interesting thing to note was the `.keyword` doesn't seem to be necessary with this method.  I am not sure why.

Comment: How to do a not contains `"pH.*"`?

Comment: @MurtazaHaji. Try this: `{  "query": { "bool":{ "must_not": [{ "regexp": {  "extra.monitor_value_name.keyword": "pH.*"  }}]}}}`. Make sure you get the square brackets where shown.

Answer (score 9):

try this in filter using Elasticsearch Query DSL:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "extra.monitor_value_name": {
        "value": "pH.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```